# Combining Multiple files to create one file

Tags: python

[image]

I've 72 table files and each one of them has 9 columns in it. Their names are something like this

- txt_1.ares
- txt_2.ares
- txt_3.ares
- txt_4.ares
- txt_5.ares
- txt_6.ares
- txt_7.ares
- txt_8.ares

I want to combine all these files to create one big file and I used the following code to do this but it's not working properly:

```
import csv
import glob

tmpFile = 'file Name'
path = 'file path'+tmpFile
outputfile = open(path, "a")

for filename in glob.glob('/home/bin/ARES/*.ares'): 
    with open(filename) as f:       
        content = f.readlines()     
    for line in content:
        outputfile.write(line)
```

Can anyone please help me out of this?

Comment: Can you check your indentation and update your question accordingly?

Comment: Do you want to make those 9 columns longer and longer with each file added or do you want to add 9 additional columns with each file?

Comment: Can you post an error, or why your code doesn't function as it should?

Comment: There's nothing wrong in the indentation i just checked. This code is working but not properly and i don't understand why. Because the total number of rows in all the table files is around 590 but it's saving only 560 in the output file. That's the main issue. @jedwards

Comment: It ain't giving any error. It works but not properly. the total number of rows in all the table files is around 590 but it's saving only 560 in the output file. That's the main issue @kosnik

Comment: My guess is there is nothing wrong.  You keep saying "around 590 lines" should be there...well, 560 is not far off.  Prior to the first "for" loop add this line: counter = 0.  Increment this after each time you write a line: counter += 1.  This will tell you exactly how many lines you have in the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using linux or any other unix based operating system, why not try:

```
cat txt_*.ares > newfile
```

Comment: SIMPLY WOW.! it worked like a magic. Thanks for the help mate.! @Moses

Comment: @gyanendersingh Please can you upvote the answer since it helped you.